# Force Windows OS to choose pagefile creation only in C:\ drive

Tags: windows, powershell, virtual-memory

i'm using AWS ami in which virtual memory is choosed option to "automatically manage by system "(most of application using that AMI) due to that, when i choose higher instance type(Memory based). OS create pagefile.sys in DB drives because higher free space is available compare to other drives( i know OS can release or shrink file size when ever there is demand) but in my case once machine boot up we have script that will change drives letter (few drives created from snapshot). If pagefile presented in drive , we cannot  change it's letter until we move to other drives( i can move pagefile to otherdrives but it required system reboot). In short, can i force os to choose pagefile creation only on C:\  while instance launches from AMI.

Answer (score 0):

"The Win32_PageFileSetting WMI class represents the settings of a page file. Information contained within objects instantiated from this class specify the page file parameters used when the file is created at system startup. The properties in this class can be modified and deferred until startup. These settings are different from the run-time state of a page file expressed through the associated class Win32_PageFileUsage."

https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_pagefilesetting
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pagefilesetting
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pagefileusage